# Find js function with firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

I have the following button:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnLogin" onclick="return ValidateLogin();" value="Enter">
```

How can i find the definition of the ValidateLogin() function with firebug?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Type the following into the Firebug Console, then click the function() in the output window

```
var s = ValidateLogin.prototype.constructor;
console.log(s); // will output the actual function definition
```

I have included some screenshots to help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It gives only the definition not the location of the function so i cant't modify it.Is there any way to modifiy that function?

Comment: in that case type `ValidateLogin` no (), then right click on the function() in the output panel, and click Inspect in Script Tab. It will then show the .js file it is located in

Comment: I just got an upvote for this in 2017. Isn't Firebug discontinued? Don't get me wrong, Firebug was the bomb, just curious

Answer (score 14):

To get the function definition only this would be a shortcut in the firebug console:

```
console.log(ValidateLogin.toString());
```

The defintion of the function will be printed to the console directly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a search field on the top right of Firebug. When you are on the Script panel and focus the search field, you'll get a small dialog which a check box "Multiple Files" (or something similar - I don't have the English version). Check it and copy the name of the Function you are looking for into it.

Answer (score 0):

go to HTML label. Here you can view also the contents of the Javascript file included in the page.

I hope it's helpful.