# How to find the URL of an external site's Javascript submit

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, external

I will do my best to try to explain this.

I am scraping a website for it's elements to then output in a different format. The problem that I am experiencing is the way that this site directs the user throughout the site is through a Javascript redirect.

When checking the 'a href' tag, this is the Javascript that shows up
    `javascript:doParamSubmit(2100, document.forms['studentFilteredListForm'], 'SSC000001MU9lI')`

The `SSC000001MU9lI` changes for each element that it redirects to.

**Is it possible to find a URL using this Javascript, so that I can reach the HTML page externally?**

---

**EDIT:** Here is the doParamSubmit and doSubmit classes:

```
function doParamSubmit(event, form, parameter) {
    form.userParam.value = parameter;
    doSubmit(event, form);
}

function doSubmit(event, form)
{
    // Make sure if something fails that the form can be resubmitted
    try
    {
        // If this form has not been submitted yet... (except for IE)
        if (allowSubmit == true && form != null && (submitted == false || isInternetExplorer6() || isInternetExplorer7()))
        {
            submitted = true;
            form.userEvent.value = event;

            // Fix for IE bug in which userEvent becomes a property array.
            if (form.userEvent.length)
            {
                form.userEvent[0].value = event;
            }

            // Disable the form so the user can't accidentally resubmit the page
            // (NOTE:  this doesn't disable links (e.g. <a href="javascript:...">)
            disableForm(form);

            // If there is a populate form function, call it. If there are spell check fields on the 
            // page, populateForm is used to set hidden field values.
            if (this.populateForm)
            {
                populateForm();
            }

            saveScrollCoordinates();
            // resetSessionTimeout();

            try
            {
                form.submit();
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                // Exceptions thrown here are only caused by canceling the submit in onbeforeunload, so ignore.
                submitted = false;
            }
        }

        if (allowSubmit == false)
        {
            alert(grabResource("message.pageLoading"));
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        submitted = false;
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read the `doParamSubmit()` function and see what it does.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I have read it. I'll add that to the code above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 approaches.

1. You use a javascript enabled browser such as http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/. I am not sure if you intend to just follow the links or instead grab the URL for some other use so your mileage may vary.
2. Find the doParamSumit() function in their page/scripts and analyze it to understand how it gets the URL - the one you have as an example looks like it grabs the action from a form perhaps?  Once you know how the function work you might be able to harness that info in your scraping by using some regex to find URLs that match the doParamSubmit pattern and going from there. It's hard to say without seeing the function itself as well as the other links like it though.

Regardless of which method you choose I would begin by understanding the function - look for it in the code or loaded js files (you can also you things like javascript debuggers on most browsers to help you find it) and see what happens - it might be super obvious.

Also keep in mind that this might be a POST for a form - in which case the result of you following that link may not work if it expects valid form data.

**Edit** I see that you posted the function. It simply submits the form listed in the second parameter i.e. 'studentFilteredListForm'. While I don't think your scraping will go to far chasing forms you can still get the URL either with javascript if your scraper lets you (something like `$('form[name=studentFilteredListForm]').attr('action')` or using whatever language your are using for the scraper i.e. find the form and extract the action url (remembering that if there is no action it is probably posting back to the current URL)

But again... you might first manually get the URL of the form and see where that gets you. You might just get a page with form errors :)

Comment: Yes, thank you! :) This was the approach I was going to begin to go after, but the js files are quite extensive and include many, many methods. Just wanted to check here first.

Comment: Something like this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469691/find-js-function-with-firebug

Comment: Yes, I've execute that snippet in the console to see how it would run, and the response was the same URL. The change was after the URL i.e. `?navkey=academics.classes.list`